# Can grails g:formRemote tag update more than one div

Tags: grails

Can g:formRemote update more than one div in grails, What would be a viable strategy for updating multiple divs? can anyone explain me this with an example...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can control the update of your page. Instead of using the `update` attribute, use the `onSuccess` event.

From the docs:

> onSuccess (optional) - The JavaScript function to call if successful

#### Example

View

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" onSuccess="updateBook(data)" method="GET"
              action="${createLink(controller: 'book', action: 'show')}"
              url="[controller: 'book', action: 'show']">
    Book Id: <input name="id" type="text" />
</g:formRemote>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function updateBook(data) {
  //do what you want here
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
def show() {
  //TODO: validate if exists and etc..
  def book = Book.get(params.id)
  render book as JSON //send JSON to the client, handling in the updateBook function.  
}
```

#### Flow

- User inform id
- Ajax request is made
- g:formRemote will call the javascript function updateBook
- data will have the JSON that you can parse and do whatever you want (update divs)